# Spanner Logging of SQL Select Statements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have turned on both the DATA_READ, DATA_WRITE logtypes but I am not able to see any SQL queries.  I have reviewed both the activity page and log views from within the GCP console.  Below are the confirmed configurations that are enabled:

auditConfigs:
- auditLogConfigs:
  - logType: DATA_READ
  - logType: DATA_WRITE
  service: spanner.googleapis.com

I have launched a query from within GCP console and reviewed the "Data" tab of a table but nothing really shows up in the log as to the columns selected or table.  We have also launched a "select" statement from within the API and still do not see any query in the log.  Is there a way to see a query and if not, what is the best that can be expected?

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be using sql statements, it seems like you'll want to set audit configs for DATA_READ.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/audit-logging#audited_operations

Comment: I actually have both read and writes enabled.  I fixed the question text to be accurate.  I am continuing to review the logs and have noticed that in the permission section it states : permission is "select."  I have also noticed that there are some log records where I the permission is read.  With the "read" permission, there are column names listed along with a table name.  Perhaps that is the API call for a "read" rather than a "select".  Again any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the [Data Access Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access) are properly enabled, then you will need one of these three roles to view them:

1. Project Owner
2. Logging's [Private Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) role
3. Some custom IAM role with the `logging.privateLogEntries.list` Cloud IAM permission

Answer (score 0):

There are entries in the logs but that do not typically show the individual query or DML statement.  In regards to performance review of queries, the best thing I have been able to find to date are the spanner statistics tables.   They provide a means as to the query duration, nbr of rows read and cpu utilization.  Here's a link:

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-stats-tables